# Where should the 'no account?' button go?

Tags: login, accessibility, signup-signon

On a website I am creating, the user is prompted to login before they can access the main content page. However, if they do not own an account, they can create one. Where should this button be placed? Is the example I've provided suitable?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding such a link close to Login button does the job very well.** Although I would choose a slightly different wording. Sign In or Log In is pretty standard these days and your Logon caught me off guard too.

Also "Don't have an account yet?" sounds a bit better.

**I would go the other way around though.** You want your website to be tailored for onboarding new users. User of your website usually knows where to sign in or are already signed in but a new visitor aren't. Saying something like "Sign up here in order to get the complete experience" would convert more visitors into users and grow your website.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer, I agree with the 'logon' part - sounds funny. I changed it to 'Sign in'. Anyway, my website is built for a very specific audience (members at my university), and the content on the sight is quite personal (upcoming events, class matters etc...) and I would like to ensure the user is logged in with a verified account (requires their university email address to create) so no person other than the students can see the material. I understand where you were going, though. Thanks a lot!